# UserDefaults Bool FAIL

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save below data using `UserDefaults` but when I pass `isDefault` bool, it does not work. But if I remove `isDefault` it works fine.

https://gist.github.com/n1tesh/4de0fea9514e392e35e241786f51e98b

```
struct User {

    var userContact  = CNContact()
    var recipientContact: CNContact?
    var isDefault: Bool = false
    init(userContact: CNContact, recipientContact: CNContact? = nil, isDefault: Bool) {
        self.userContact = userContact
        self.recipientContact = recipientContact
        self.isDefault = isDefault
    }

}

extension User {
    @objc(_TtCV6testUD4User6Coding)class Coding: NSObject, NSCoding {

        let model: User?

        init(model: User) {
            self.model = model
            super.init()
        }

        func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
            guard let model = self.model else {
                return
            }

            aCoder.encode(model.userContact, forKey: "userContact")
            aCoder.encode(model.recipientContact, forKey: "recipientContact")
            aCoder.encode(model.isDefault, forKey: "isDefault")

        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            guard let userContact = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userContact") as? CNContact,let isDefault = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "isDefault") as? Bool  else  {
                    return nil
            }
          let recipientContact = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "recipientContact") as? CNContact

            model = User(userContact: userContact, recipientContact: recipientContact, isDefault: isDefault)
            super.init()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't encode a `Bool` using `NSCoder`, it's not an Objective-C type. I suggest you scrap this approach and just use `Codable` in Swift 4.

Comment: Define "does not work". That's not helpful. In what way exactly doesn't it work?

Comment: @JonShier I want it to support on iOS 10 too.

Comment: @rmaddy When I Save `isDefault` bool and when I try to decode the object, it returns nil.

Comment: @Nitesh: `Codable` supports iOS 10. It's a Swift 4 feature, not an SDK one.

Comment: @JonShier Can you please share an example.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of `NSCoding` `Bool` is not an object. Use the dedicated method `decodeBool(forKey`

```
let isDefault = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "isDefault")
```

The result is a non-optional `Bool`